# Can't access the setting.setting file while runing the .exe

Tags: c#, connection-string, setting

I have stored only the database location and database name in settings.settings file.I'm able to access the connection string from Settings.Settings file while debugging. But When i run the the executable it doesn't load the database that i  used in connection string in setting.settings file.The user can dynamically changes the Settings file As per user need. My connection string is like-

```
public static string sd =System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.ToString();

public static string co = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sd +"\\Data\\"+ Properties.Settings.Default.db+".accdb";
```

Comment: So what does `BaseDirectory.ToString()`  and `Properties.Settings.Default.db` return? Can you log the returned value and see it.

Comment: Yes..for testing purpose i used MessageBox.Show(), Which returns desired result when debugging. But when i run the .exe it shows a different database that is not saved in Properties.Settings.Default.db.....BaseDirectory.ToString() , also shows the desired result.

Comment: The settings file change it so it is per application and not per user unless you want it user based. You can do that using project properties and going to settings. Also you may just wanna save the connection string in `AppSettings` instead. Sorry i would write the answer but I am outside on my mobile phone.

Comment: Ok....let me try by changing it to per user not per application.where i can find it in settings?

Comment: I have changed the that particular setting to application based. Now its works also with .exe .The problem I'm facing now is the user should dynamically change the settings.setting file. I was working while it was set to user based in debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the properties of the project and make it application based instead of user based.

> .The problem I'm facing now is if the user should dynamically change the settings.setting file

No the user cannot do this dynamically as the file is locked by the application. If the user makes a change, a restart of the application is required but then again the change can only occur when the file is not locked by the app.

There is no point in making a connection string user based unless each user should have different connection string.

**EDIT**

If you want to change the connection dynamically then either treat the settings file like an XML file and modify it or store the connection string in another source like a file or database.

Comment: I need to change the connection string dynamically ....and i restart the application every time setting changes.